.Net Maui - Not able to render images coming down from API in svg format
I have an api which give me image in svg format. I know .NET Maui converts svg to png during app start but I need to do this after.
Is there option I can follow to do this ? My issue is even if i download the image and change it's extension to .png it does not load. When i convert the svg to png it works.

This question is similar to: How to show an svg image after download in Maui. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's almost similar but the image is not rendering until i convert it to png. But i don't want to do that . @Jason

please read the 2nd answer to that question

I have svg as a string not a file coming down from api . Not sure how can i save it inside the resource/Image folder to access it with .png extension

How are displaying the SVG? I could be wrong, but I think you need some sort of a WebView to display a SVG.

did you even read the post I linked to?  The 2nd answer is a custom SVG control, it has nothing to do with reading a png from resources.

Managed to make it work with some modification. Thanks @Jason
